# Maximize partial sum of binomials

Tags: optimization, binomial-coefficients

During my research I got to the point when I need to find

$$
\arg \max_w \left( (n-w) \sum_{j=0}^d \binom{w}{j} \binom{2^r - (j+1) 2^{r-j-1}-2}{t} \right)
$$

with respect to $w$ only (i.e. $d$, $n$, $r$ and $t$ are considered as integer constants).

Again, I don't need *the value* of the maximized expression, I need only $w$ which maximizes the expression.

I could see some obvious conditions on the parameters (like $d \leqslant w$) but nothing interesting.

Combinatorics and sums are not my field so I don't really know what to do with this and what I can do *in principle*.

Approximations would be fine too, provided they are not too rough. Any hints or links would be also appreciated.

Comment: Presumably w is greater than d? But then the sum will be an increasing function of w with no maximum, no?

Comment: For $w > n$ the function will be negative... So maximum exist somewhere in $[0,n]$.

Comment: Right, sorry - must take more time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that many terms are irrelevant in terms of optimization. Thus, we can rewrite the problem as
$$
\arg\max_w \left( (n-w)\sum_{j=0}^d {w\choose j}\alpha_j\right)
$$
Since the combination numbers can be expressed using [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#The_Gamma_and_Pi_functions), we can write
$$
 (n-w)\sum_{j=0}^d {w\choose j}\alpha_j= (n-w)\sum_{j=0}^d \frac{w!}{(w-j)!j!}\alpha_j=(n-w)\sum_{j=0}^d \frac{\Gamma(w+1)}{\Gamma(w-j+1)\Gamma(j+1)}\alpha_j
$$
which is continuous in $w$ and can be subject of differentiation and standard optimization methods and tools.

Comment: Hm... indeed, seems so. I'll get back after trying this.

Comment: Well, the first try is not really successful. Taking derivative by $w$ ends up with equation involving sum of gammas and derivatives of gamma. I will try to further simplify since analytical expression of $w$ is strongly desirable.

Comment: Idea: Consider polynomial approximation of $\Gamma$ around $w$ using Taylor expansion and work with derivatives of this polynomial approximation.